# MySQL query gives not enough arguments error on Django

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME (unixtime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS ndate, count(id) AS query_count FROM myTable GROUP BY ndate ORDER BY query_count DESC
```

When i execute this query on PHPMyadmin it will work without any problem. When i try to execute it from Django i get the following error:

```
Summary = myTable.objects.raw("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME (unixtime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS ndate, count(id) AS query_count FROM myTable GROUP BY ndate ORDER BY query_count DESC")

>>not enough arguments for format string
```

I don't understand why does that happen, since Django should just esecute the raw MySQL query. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I would guess the '%' characters are interpreted as formatting characters, and they need to be escaped (or you need to provide values).

Comment: Thanks! How can i escape those characters? Maybe by assigning them to a variable and then concatenate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> (unixtime, '%Y/%m/%d')
> ```

You want this instead:

```
(unixtime, '%%Y/%%m/%%d')
```

In python, `%s` e.g. has special meaning within a format string.
And `%%` works out to just a single percent character.
So by the time Django has produced a formatted string
and has sent that to the DB backend,
the date format will contain single percents, as required.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is being caused because '%Y/%m/%d' implies string substitution. Try:

```
Summary = myTable.objects.raw("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME (unixtime, '%Y/%m/%%d') AS ndate, count(id) AS query_count FROM myTable GROUP BY ndate ORDER BY query_count DESC")
```